# How to add Scala 3 specific functionality in a cross built project?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-3

I am building a Scala library using

```
ThisBuild / crossScalaVersions := List("2.13.8", "3.2.0")
```

This works as long as I use Scala 2 syntax for the entire project for compatibility. When I run command `+publish` from `sbt`, it publishes two modules, one prefixed with `2.13` and another one prefixed with `_3`.

I now want to build some exclusive functionality for Scala 3 users in the Scala 3 generated artefact. More specifically, I want to provide a macro derivation for scala 3 users.

How do I do that?

Comment: How detailed answer do you need? Documentation has a dedicated page just for your case: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/tutorial-macro-cross-building.html

Comment: @bilal-fazlani You can put sources to corresponding sub-directory: `scala` - for sources that are shared across all versions of Scala, `scala-3` - for Scala 3 only sources, `scala-2` for Scala 2 only sources, like [here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/tree/master/jsoniter-scala-macros/shared/src/main) or [here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/tree/master/jsoniter-scala-macros/shared/src/test).

Comment: Thank you Mateusz and Andriy. This helped